# How to develop sections in iOS with page controls

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, storyboard

how can I write an iOs 7 app that has sections whose navigation is based on the [page control](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIPageControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIPageControl) element? Just like twitter's Home, Discover and Activity sessions, in picture below

[image]

How can I do this? I want 3 sections too. Does Xcode's Storyboard have any special feature to help me accomplish this?

I'm quite a newbie in iOS development and I appreciate any help you could give me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An app like that can be set up with a UITabBarController at the root.  The first tab would be a UIPageViewController.  In the UIPageViewController would have 3 pages.  Each of the pages would be a UITableViewController.